# Pexpect long input

Tags: python, putty, tty

Its hard to explain what I am doing, but in short, the log/output of pexpect is getting messed up because of long input string that I am providing... Its similar to what happens in a Putty session having a small (physical) window size

For example,

```
! Using Python
# Python2.6
# Windows 7, Cygwin
# Psuedo-Code - I am giving this
p = pexpect.spawn('ssh Router')
p.sendline('show logging | include MLSCEF-DFC1-2-FIB_TCAM_WRITE_INCONSISTENCY')
i = p.expect('Router#')
print p.before

# Output Seen as 
Router# show logging | include MLSCEF-DFC1-2-FIB_TCAM_WRITE$g | include MLSCEF-DFC1-2-FIB_TCAM_WRITE_         INCONSISTe MLSCEF-DFC1-2-FIB_TCAM_WRITE_INCONSISTE         NCY

! Using Putty
# This is seen from a tiny putty session for Router
# Really I am just Copy Pasting the line "show logging | include MLSCEF-DFC1-2-FIB_TCAM_WRITE_INCONSISTENCY" into Putty and finally, putty looks like this
ur01.steubenville.oh.pitt#$EF-DFC1-2-FIB_TCAM_WRITE_INCONSISTENCY

# If I increase the windows size of the putty, I see the whole output
ur01.steubenville.oh.pitt#show logging | include MLSCEF-DFC1-2-FIB_TCAM_WRITE_INCONSISTENCY
```

Another way to explain, this is what is happening even with pexpect - 
http://support.suso.com/supki/File:Nano-pasted-authorizedkeys.png

Ultimately, I want pexpect increase input windows size so that I don't get to see the dollar sign ($)?

Comment: Please note, using maxread, doesn't do anything

Comment: setwinsize(100, 100) doesn't do anything either